# python regex doesnt match when run from cron

Tags: python, regex, cron, rhel

I'm having difficulty getting a regex to match when the job is run from cron. When I run it from the cmd line it works just fine.

I have some output from an ssh session that I need to parse for some CPU data.

```
parts = \x1b[7mlines 24-46 \x1b[27m\x1b[K\r\x1b[KCPU 9

parts = \x1b[7mlines 25-47 \x1b[27m\x1b[K\r\x1b[K Utilization: 57%

parts = Peak Utilization Last Hour: 100% at 2014/04/09 07:07:12

parts = Avg. Utilization Last Hour: 67%

parts = 

parts = \x1b[7mlines 48-70 \x1b[27m\x1b[K\r\x1b[K

parts = \x1b[7mlines 49-71 \x1b[27m\x1b[K\r\x1b[KCPU 14

parts = Utilization: 46%
```

The sample above just has the problem output. Call it "sshoutput"  I need to remove `\x1b[7mlines X-X \x1b[27m\x1b[K\r\x1b[K` from an lines that contain it. This formats the output correctly for the parsing function that I made.

regex used: `\\x1b\[7mlines [0-9]*-[0-9]* \\x1b\[27m\\x1b\[K\\r\\x1b\[K`

Code that removes the problem characters:

```
ansi_char = re.compile('\\x1b\[7mlines [0-9]*-[0-9]* \\x1b\[27m\\x1b\[K\\r\\x1b\[K')

def strip_ansi(with_ansi):
    return ansi_char.sub('', with_ansi)

strip_ansi(sshoutput.before)
```

This is part of a larger script. When I run it from the prompt, it runs fine and creates the output with all data and correct formatting. When cron runs it, all the lines with the ansi crap dont get matched and some CPU data goes missing. The output is formatted correctly but do to some CPU lines not getting the ansi characters stripped, the data gets shifted and is incorrect.

I've been researching issues with cron and environment variables.  the cron locale is POSIX and mine is en_US.UTF-8.  I thought maybe this had somethign to do with how the regex would be handled.  there are tons of jobs in the crontab file and i cant do something globally.  I did try this:

```
*/1 **** export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; /pathtomyscript/myscript.py
```

Is there something else I could try in the crontab file, or can my regex be changed?

Thanks for any help/suggestions that the community may provide.

PS, im also a linux nub (RHEL 5.9) and python nub (Python 2.7).  I know enough to be dangerous :)

Comment: The coloring you see on the command line (eg, \x1b[7m) probably isn't there when run from cron. Maybe you could hack up some terminal thing (TERM=xterm, etc) but how about just saving the data you want to process from the cron job and adjusting your regex accordingly?

Comment: So the reason the regex was added was to remove the characters.  i know the characters are being returned when the script is run with the cron job.  i should also add that the ssh session from the python script is using pxssh.   the output is the same as if i didn't add the regex part.  This (and various debug print statements) leads me to this conclusion.

Comment: So tried a couple more things with no luck.  i created a shell script that sources my profiles environment before running the python script.  that didnt work.  i also tried "sudo -u myusername /path to script"  in the crontab file.  also didnt work.

Comment: Here's a regex the removes ansi escape sequences (note the 'r' at the front of the string so that I don't have to escape the backslash) `r'\1b\[\d*[a-zA-Z]'`. You could do a second regex from there. Or potentially remove all the junk with `r'\1b\[\d*[a-zA-Z]|\r|lines \d*-\d*\s*'`.

Comment: After playing with the environment variables when running the job, someone suggested setting the TERM from the python script.  this ended up working and im not entirely positive why.  os.environ["TERM"] = "xterm-256color" was the line added to the code.  im guessing this sets the term variable to something so that no matter who runs it, the TERM is always the same.  this value allowed the regex to work under my profile and crons.  im guessing that when the ssh commands in the code were run, the ansi codes were slightly different, due to the different TERM value for my account and cron.

Comment: Hence the suggestion to save the data from the cron job so you could see what it was. Coloring apps that spit out ansi sequences do different ones depending on terminal type. The regex that strips ansi sequences should also have helped remove the variable part.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing there is termcap codes for displaying things based on the kind of display device connected. When you run that command from cron, there is no connected device. Your program isn't giving you the same data.

Here are three possible ways to get the same data:

1) Maybe, you can set the terminal environment variable and your program might (!!) work the same. It not very likely. In cron "TERM=vt100OrSomething /pathtomyscript/myscript.py" . No "export" or semicolon or anything.

2) You could run it detached inside screen or tmux, and use their terminal emulation. Or, you could use Expect's "unbuffer" program.  You'll have to change your code to match what it sends for tmux's fake termainal.

3) Connect normally, and unset your "TERM" env variable, and then you'll be a lot like the cron environment. Don't try to make the crazy, unknown cron environment like your interactive session is. Make your interactive session like your cron environment is, and solve it there.

Of all these, I think you should go with #3.  Start sub-shells to test:

```
$ vi program    
$ bash    
$ unset TERM; PS1=\$\$    
$$ ./program    
$$ exit    
$ vi program    
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, only in my case I was running "ifconfig -a" to fetch IPv6 and IPv4 info from the Linux Server included in my python script.

From terminal, the RegEx and the output printed in the console worked perfectly, but executed from cron job I got "blank".

So, this is the solution:

When in your script, you provide the bash command to be executed (in your case let say it was "top") in my case "ifconfig -a", you have to provide the full path for this app/utility/command within your Linux machine.

I had this (ERROR):

```
import subprocess
ifconfig_command = "ifconfig -a"
run_ifconfig_command = subprocess.Popen(ifconfig_command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).stdout.read()
```

Instead you should use the entire path for the command (SUCCESSFUL):

```
import subprocess
ifconfig_command = "/usr/sbin/ifconfig -a"
run_ifconfig_command = subprocess.Popen(ifconfig_command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).stdout.read()
```

From this point on, my RegEx started working when I compare it to `run_ifconfig_command`

I know it's 7 years later since this post, but I hope it can help anyone with this or similar issue.

PD: for any command or utility full path, you can use:

```
which <*command or utility*>
```

And it should provide the entire location for the installation folder of the command.